# Outlier detection

Tags: python, machine-learning, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have a daily dataset with Product Name and Sales amount (in CSV format)
This data is for last 1 year.
I need to find the medium of the sales amount for each product and create a Model with Product Name and medium value for the sales amount

Now when I  give today's data with Product Name and Sales amount, the model should give me product names whose sales amount varies from +/--
10% of the medium value from the model.

**Sample data**

```
ProductName,Date,Amount
P1,01-01-2019,1000
p2,01-01-2019,1000
p3,01-01-2019,1000
P1,02-01-2019,1878
p2,02-01-2019,1540
p3,02-01-2019,1482
P1,04-01-2019,2010
p2,04-01-2019,2540
p3,04-01-2019,2365
P1,06-01-2019,995
p2,06-01-2019,860
p3,06-01-2019,1000
```

Comment: Any code to share?

Comment: ProductName,Date,Amount
P1,01-01-2019,1000
p2,01-01-2019,1000
p3,01-01-2019,1000
P1,02-01-2019,1878
p2,02-01-2019,1540
p3,02-01-2019,1482
P1,04-01-2019,2010
p2,04-01-2019,2540
p3,04-01-2019,2365
P1,06-01-2019,995
p2,06-01-2019,860
p3,06-01-2019,1000

Comment: Edit the question and add it in question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not able to provide any code of what you have done, and this site is not to provide code for you.
But still seeing you are new here:

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ProductName = [
    'P1', 'p2', 'p3', 'P1', 'p2', 'p3', 'P1', 'p2', 'p3', 'P1', 'p2', 'p3'
]
Date = [
    '01-01-2019', '01-01-2019', '01-01-2019', '02-01-2019', '02-01-2019',
    '02-01-2019', '04-01-2019', '04-01-2019', '04-01-2019', '06-01-2019',
    '06-01-2019', '06-01-2019'
]
Amount = [1000, 1000, 1000, 1878, 1540, 1482, 2010, 2540, 2365, 995, 860, 1000]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name': ProductName, 'Date': Date, 'Amount': Amount})
df_Product = df.groupby('Product Name').median()

data = {'ProductName':'P1','Date':'03-04-2019','Amount':1525}
for index,row in df_Product.iterrows():
    if data['Amount'] >= row['Amount'] - 0.1*row['Amount'] and data['Amount'] <= row['Amount'] + 0.1*row['Amount']:
        print(index)
```

Comment: This could be your starter code and try applying `scikit SVM` for Anomaly Detection.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to detect outliers. They are Z-score based mode, statistics based detection or machine learning-based Outlier detection.

Recently, I am using a statistic based OD detecting mode for multi-dimension data set. This mode will need `statsmodels` library.

Here is sample code:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.stats import zscore
    
    df=pd.DataFrame(Your_sample_data)
    y_col = "amount"
    X_cols = ["ProductName","Date"]
    X=df[X_cols]
    y=df[OD_y_col]
    
    lm = sm.OLS(y,X).fit()
    OD_result =lm.outlier_test()
    
    print(lm.summary())
    print(OD_result[OD_result.unadj_p<=confidence_level]）
```

Hope above Pseudocode  could help you.